# How do I apply my script to only rows with the checkbox clicked

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

How do I fix my script to only run if the checkbox is clicked and turned FALSE?

```
  function newIntake() {
  const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('15BmXFulTrk5KdupjaH3HgqHzuI-vWxtqNQO9brkRc20');
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1OoahvXeYkldkVHee49QYFOSbkPOCqkfo');
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Data');

  const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  rows.forEach(function(row, index){
    if (index === 0) return;
    if (row[5]) return; 
    var filteredRows = rows.filter(row)
       if (row[4] === 'FALSE')return;
    });

    const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`${row[1]},${row[0]} New Intake`, destinationFolder)
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId())
    const body = doc.getBody();
    const friendlyDate = new Date (row[3]).toLocaleDateString();
    body.replaceText('{{Date}}', friendlyDate);
    body.replaceText('{{Intake By}}', row[1]);
    body.replaceText('{{Client Name}}', row[2]);
    body.replaceText('{{DoB}}', row[3]);
    doc.saveAndClose();
    const url = doc.getUrl();
    sheet.getRangeList(['F2:F400']).setValue(url);
 
  }
```

This is what I currently have but I am not sure where the error is

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please briefly describe your spreadsheet and how the script is used (are  you running it from the script editor, using an installable trigger...?)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have a typo while doing filtering rows, and also I think you do not use the result of the filtering

```
 var filteredRows = rows.filter(row)
    if (row[4] === 'FALSE')return;
 });
```

Try to do it like this:

```
  // here is the filtering of the rows
  var filteredRows = rows.filter((row, i) => i !== 0 && !row[5] && row[4] !== 'FALSE');
  filteredRows.forEach(function(row, index) {
    // below is just a copy of the rest of the code
    const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`${row[1]},${row[0]} New Intake`, destinationFolder)
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId())
    const body = doc.getBody();
    const friendlyDate = new Date (row[3]).toLocaleDateString();
    body.replaceText('{{Date}}', friendlyDate);
    body.replaceText('{{Intake By}}', row[1]);
    body.replaceText('{{Client Name}}', row[2]);
    body.replaceText('{{DoB}}', row[3]);
    doc.saveAndClose();
    const url = doc.getUrl();
    sheet.getRangeList(['F2:F400']).setValue(url);
  });
```

First you filter the rows, then you do `forEach` over the filtered rows

Comment: Thank you so much I am new to learning coding and teaching myself so this is super helpful